# Nginx upstream loadbalancing: auto retrying of 502's?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

If I have nginx loadbalancing for multiple upstream reverse proxies, and one of them goes down, will my user get a 502, or will nginx take care of re-routing to an upstream that is up?

Comment: Nginx will automatically respond to your user using the available upstream servers. If you have at least one upstream server working, no one should get a 502.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, have this exact problem. Good question.

Answer (score 5):

from the [documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamModule#upstream)

> If with an attempt at the work with the server error occurred, then
>   the request will be transmitted to the following server and then until
>   all workers of server not are tested. If successful answer is not
>   succeeded in obtaining from all servers, then to client will be
>   returned the result of work with the last server.

Comment: I read that this morning actually, but to answer my question I would  need to know what counts as an error to get this treatment? `proxy_next_upstream` defaults to `error timeout`, but wasn't sure if i had to include `http_502` in there as well, or if including that would mean that nginx was able to connect to the upstream, and the upstream explicitly returned 502 as opposed to just not being available

Comment: I think nginx checks for one of these conditions to be true

Comment: BTW for ``error`` the documentation says ``an error occurred while establishing a connection with the server, passing it a request, or reading its response`` and in this case nginx doesn't have the possibility to read the 502 status code.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically you want

```
proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
```

I put mine in the 'http' block so it'd be the default for my several services.  Unfortunately 500-504 is NOT on the default for nginx.